# Probability in NetLogo - using one-of or creating a random number

Tags: netlogo

I was wondering if by using same random seed, the result of following functions differs significantly in randomness! and which one is better? provided Code is just an example.

```
let b random 3
if b = 0 [set Output "Output1"]  
if b = 1 [set Output "Output2"]  
if b = 2 [set Output "Output3"]


Or this one :   
set output one-of ["Output1" "Output2" "Output3"]
```

- UPdate:

I just checked it with a simple netlogo program:

```
turtles-own [X Y A]

to setup
  __clear-all-and-reset-ticks

  create-turtles 50
  [set A random 3000
   set y random-normal 0.5 0.1
   set x random-normal 0.5 0.1
   move-to patch random 20 random 20]
end

to go
  ask turtles
  [ set A A + 1
    fd 1
    rt random 10 
    if A > 4000 [die]
    if random-float 1 < 0.003 and a > 1000 and A < 3000 [
      let xx x
      let yy y
      hatch 1
      [ set A 0
        set x one-of (list  (random-normal 0.5 0.1) (xx + 0.1) (XX - 0.1))
        let b random 3
        if b = 0 [set y random-normal 0.5 0.1]
        if b = 1 [set y yy + 0.1]
        if b = 2 [set y yy - 0.1 ]

        ]
      ]

    ]
  tick
end
```

The results is as follow:

[image]

There is not much difference is using any of these methods :)

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, ask on the NetLogo support group at Google groups, since you'll probably need an answer from one of the developers (or someone who's willing to go through the source code to find the answer).  However, some of the developers periodically answer questions here.

Comment: Thanks Mars, I will try that if I don't get an answer here , but I just remembered that I can   test it myself in a simple netlogo program, but since I am new there might be other aspects that I dont know about :)

Comment: Nice test, and you have your answer from the main developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug in your measurement code. Change `b = 3` to `b = 2` and I predict you will see any difference go away.

Unless there is some weird bug in NetLogo (or the JVM) that no one has discovered yet, it shouldn't make any difference whether you use `one-of` or `random`.  To my knowledge, there is no such bug.

The relevant source files are:

- https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/blob/5.0.x/src/main/org/nlogo/prim/_randomconst.java
- https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/blob/5.0.x/src/main/org/nlogo/prim/_oneof.java

The only difference is that the first calls `context.job.random.nextLong` and the latter `context.job.random.nextInt` (because the size of a NetLogo list is an int, not a long, while the input to `random` is a long). But both `nextInt` and `nextLong` are of equally high quality; they're just calls into the standard [MersenneTwisterFast](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/blob/5.0.x/src/main/org/nlogo/util/MersenneTwisterFast.java) class which is widely used by people doing simulation work.

Comment: Thanks for ponting that, I fixed it, in my own program I was using 2 but in the test one I dont know why I wrote 3!

Comment: I was wondering if there is any function in netlogo to generate random float between zero and 1 ? I think my question might be stupid so I don't want to ask a new question in the forum :) (like Math.max or Math.min in java) I am using random-normal 0.5 0.1, but in my main program there is a concept of inheritance and there might be cases with bigger than 1 or less than zero values. there is a chance of -0.1 or 0.1 variation of the variable for child and parents.

Comment: `random-float 1` will give you a random float between 0 and 1.

Comment: Yes, Thats correct:)  I meant that to put a limit on the variable itself, I know I did not ask the right question, my problem is in the inheritance ,  I use a check after calculating value for child agent to see by variation of -.1 and +0.1 the value is still in the range, thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Oh, I think I understand now what you want. Go ahead and ask it as a separate question, it's not stupid.